# How to change or add Status names in dynamic crm 2013 - Opportunity entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to change Status names of opportunity entity and add another status.

Is it possible to do without programming ? There are some tools for doing it?

If not possible without programming can someone post a reference how to do it ? I know some C# code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the opportunity entity the `Status` values are Open, Won, Lost and these cannot be changed.

For each `Status` there is one or more `Status Reason` which you can update, delete or add new values to as required.

Note that the attribute names for `State` and `Status Reason` are `statecode` and `statuscode` respectively when you're looking at the entity in customisations.

Comment: Thanks. 
I know how to change the Status Reason. I had a programmer that changed also the names of Open / Won / Lost. Our dynamic is not in English - maybe he did it with translation ?

Comment: Yes this is almost certainly what they did unless they updated them directly in the database which is certainly not supported.  However, you still won't be able to add new values to the Status this way.

Comment: Thanks you Darren Lewis! 
Beside the fact it is not supported, would it make errors or other issues to change the names directly from DB ?

Comment: Difficult to say, might do, might not, that's one of the reasons it isn't a supported change